# How to know who has deleted a project in OpenProject

Tags: openproject

We have multiple admins in OpenProjects. One of the project is deleted and now we are unable to debug who has deleted the project. If we delete a project from application instead of soft delete the record is deleted from the database. Now we are unable to debug it. We have checked logs but of no use.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should search on google for this.

Comment: I've already searched @ShubhamVerma